# Firefox won't sync when SmartProxy (or FoxyProxy) is enabled

Tags: firefox, proxy, sync

I'm behind a corporate proxy server and I had no issues with this until a couple of months ago. First I was using FoxyProxy, and one day I realized that Firefox wasn't syncing so I started troubleshooting (Troubleshoot mode) and found out that when a proxy addon (now I moved to SmartProxy and it's the same) is enabled Sync fails. I even tried setting up a new profile with a different, new, Firefox Sync account and the outcome is the same. Anyone else having this trouble? Is this a bug? Should I report it? Anyone wants to help me reproduce it? Thanks in advance!

PS: This happens on my Windows 10 machine too.

Here's the [Sync log](https://pastebin.com/azRHQtdL)

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what is this corporate proxy and what has changed with it
that causes this problem.

It's possible that your proxy sends an "Authorization" header with the
authentication info, and perhaps the corporate proxy is now stripping
or modifying that header.

You could try using a VPN instead of a proxy, but the corporate proxy
might also block that option. Your company is apparently beefing up
its security with some measures, perhaps designed to block infected computers
from sending hidden data to their control center.

Comment: Then why does Sync works when I disable the proxy extensions? I'm still using the same proxy, only this time it's configured in Firefox settings directly. I will post my Sync log...

Comment: The log says that getting `https://profile.accounts.firefox.com/v1/profile` failed with the error of `NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST`, meaning the above website couldn't be reached. I don't know what your two proxies, personal and corporate, do to make this site unreachable. Perhaps you should ask your network administrator.

Comment: That's the only error I can see too! It's the same proxy server, the difference is that when I don't use the extension Sync works perfectly, and when I do enable the extension Sync stop working due to `NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST`. Opening that URL directly on the browser works OK on both cases. Maybe I should reach out to the addon developers...

Comment: You could try posting a bug report. Your log will be useful.